# Destroying a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on a Matrix class that is implemented with a vector of vectors like so:

```
class Matrix {
    private:
        int r, c;
        std::vector<std::vector<double> > grid;
    public:
        //things
```

Currently I am implementing the destructor, and had a thought about it. Before I (smartly) made the switch to the `std::vector` I was using a `double ** grid`. That meant a fair bit of `new` calls since each pointer pointed to an array (which are also pointers I believe...or errors I encountered have suggested anyhow...). Regardless, the destructor looked like:

```
Matrix::~Matrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        delete [] grid[i]
    delete [] grid
```

Now I am trying to replicate that (perhaps unnecessarily?) and have the following:

```
Matrix::~Matrix() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double> >::iterator it = this->grid.begin();
    for (it; it != this->grid.end(); it++) {
       (*it).clear()
    this->grid.clear();
    std::vector<std::vector<double> >().swap(this->grid);
```

and

```
Matrix::~Matrix() {
    this->grid.clear();
    std::vector<std::vector<double> >().swap(this->grid);
```

My inclination is to go with the latter, since `clear()` should completely destroy the internal vectors (not just the contents of the internal vectors) and then the *copy and swap idiom-ish* effect of the temporary vector to deallocate the memory of the original outer vector. The former makes me think that I `clear()` the contents of each internal vector, but am left with n-number of empty, still in memory, vectors and would have to call the temporary swap mechanic on each one (and thus potentially [untested] impacting my iterator).

Does calling `clear()` on the outer vector completely deallocate the memory used for the internal vectors by calling their destructor? I am not sure if their destructor deallocates in a manner that the swap idiom does.

Comment: No need, all the vectors have their own destructors.

Comment: @Galik No need for...which part?

Comment: The correct destructor for your `Matrix` class looks like this:

Comment: No need for you to write a destructor.

Comment: @Galik Even at all? The class has a custom copy constructor and copy assignment operator; big 3?? Further, I though that if I deleted all the internal vectors, the outer one still stays around.

Comment: @KerrekSB Looks like what?

Comment: The vectors destroy themselves. Nothing for you to do.

Comment: @Galik So this is just overkill? Feels wrong to violate the big 3...I'm straight out of university so I have been hammered with that for years.

Comment: The big 3? What has that got to do with destructors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163759/discussion-between-pstatix-and-galik).

Comment: Why do you have a custom copy constructor and assignment operator? What do they do?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Again, straight out of university, big 3 was literally hammered into our skulls; the chat link has since resolved that and I have removed from my code since I am not managing resources and the smart classes are.

Comment: The guideline behind the big 3 is that if you need to define one (copy ctor, copy assign or destructor), you probably need the other 2, not that you should always define all three.

Comment: And adding to @BenjaminLindley: Now that all your members are self-cleaning (so you have no manually managed resources), you probably don't need *any* of the big 3; define none of them, and the compiler will generate all of them for you correctly (and under C++11 and higher, the move constructor and move assignment operators as well), with no effort on your part. Even more important than the rule of 3 here is [the rule of 0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).

Comment: The rule is: First call custom destructor and then default destructors for each of the members of the class. Since your vector is a RAII object, it's default destructor deallocates all memory automatically for you. That's why you don't need to write a destructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pay attention, this destructor is trickier than you think. Here we go:

```
⁣
```

Okay, actually, it's not. You can thank the [rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) for this nimble implementation. Since `std::vector` is a well-behaved class (template) that correctly manages its resources through [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii), the default-generated destructor for your class does the right thing™ without you typing anything.

If, for any reason, you still need an explicit signature for that destructor, you can use the following syntax inside your class:

```
~Matrix() = default;
```

Or, if you need the definition to be out-of-line, declare the destructor normally but define it thusly:

```
Matrix::~Matrix() = default;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write explicit destructor. default destructor sequence will take care of destruction part when you go out of scope of this 2D vector definition. Each element of 2D vector is a 1D vector and each element of 1D vector is `double` , so default destruction sequence will first destroy grid[0] as shown in the below figure, which in turn destroy each `double` element stored in grid[0], after that it will repeat the same for grid[1] and so on.

```
                                       _____  
             _____ grid[0] of doubles |_|_|_|....
            |_____ grid[1] of double
    grid--> |_____ grid[2] of double
            |_____ grid[3] of double
            |_____ grid[4] of double
```